# HTTP 404: The resource cannot be found after switching computers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, http-status-code-404

I am a new programmer and I have a small vb.net project I've been working on a while in VS2019 that has run just fine up until yesterday. After switching to a new computer I cannot get the project to run at all. I'm attempting to run it with the button 'IIS Express (Google Chrome)'.

I keep running into:

"The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /loginForm.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0"

I've toyed with about everything I can think of or research including:
-working with the start page
-trying to make sure the correct .net framework is installed
-randomly switching all of the different properties of the project
-turning on iis/.net and many of the child elements in Windows

I feel sure I'm dealing with some type of file pathing issue due to switching machines but I can't seem to figure out what the computer is expecting as the proper path. Or maybe I'm wrong all together.

Any clue to research would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Have you tried starting Visual Studio with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.